# Let $\mu$ be a measure on $X$ and suppose $\mu(A_n)\nearrow c$ exists. Then is it true that $\lim\mu(A_n')=c$ where $A_n'=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i$?

Tags: measure-theory

We have $A_n'=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i$. Then $A_{n+1}'\supset A_n'$. Then $\lim\mu(A_n')=\mu(\bigcup A_n')=\lim \mu(\bigcup A_n)$.

So the question reduces to does $\mu(\bigcup A_n)=\lim\mu(A_n)=c$? It's true if $A_n$'s are increasing but what about if $A_n$'s are not? Given that $\{\mu(A_n)\}$ are increasing sequence.

Comment: I have posted an answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure in $\Bbb R$. For $n>0$, let $A_n= \left[n, n+1-\frac{1}{n} \right]$.

We have $\mu(A_n)\nearrow 1$ and  $\mu(\bigcup_n A_n) = +\infty \ne 1= \lim_n\mu(A_n)$.